# What improvement is needed in my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

My question: [What is the minimum salary possible in a Her Majesty's Government's Department's job?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/68108/34768)

I am specific to Her Majesty's Government. Someone kind added the correct tag. I have added link. What is the flaw in the question?

[Question revision at the time of posting here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/68108/6)

[Revision after Joe W's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/68108/8)

[Revision after Rick Smith's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/68108/9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following may identify clearly those to whom you are referring; that is, the "560,000 civil servants and other staff."

[Government of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_the_United_Kingdom)

> The Government of the United Kingdom, domestically referred to as Her Majesty's Government, is the central government of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland.

[Ministers and departments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_the_United_Kingdom#Ministers_and_departments)

> As of 2019, there are around 120 government ministers supported by 560,000 civil servants and other staff working in the 25 ministerial departments and their executive agencies. There are also an additional 20 non-ministerial departments with a range of further responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You have slowly fixed a lot of the problems but when it was posted it wasn't clear exactly what level of government you were talking about. While you might be familiar with exactly how the different layers of government work in the UK not everyone does and it can get confusing with 4 separate countries that make up the whole as well as the layer that is above them all.

There is also still a minor issue that you only refer to full time employees as a requirement at the very end of your post which makes it look like a footnote and can be easy to overlook.

Looking at it a bit closer there is still an issue where you seem to want to exclude certain departments such as the police but there doesn't seem to be any criteria for which ones should be excluded.